# How to remove this icon(update manager)?

Tags: icons, panel

this icon, i mean. It is not beautiful. I have to remove it.

[image: problem]

Comment: Update your system?

Comment: Okey. ill try..

Comment: @garethTheRed But if i dont wanna update?

Comment: Then an _ugly_ icon is the least of your worries ;-)

Comment: @garethTheRed I updated. but this badge remained. I updated the picture in Q.

Comment: Now that's a _beautiful_ icon - it says that you are much safer on the Internet than you were when you had the _ugly_ icon :-)

Comment: Linux is really customizable ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really dislike it, carry out the following:

Start **Update Manager**.

From the **Edit** menu, select **Preferences**.  Tick **Only show a tray icon when updates are available or in case of errors**.

Optionally, un-tick **Show a warning if system snapshots are not set up**.  Alternatively, take a system snapshot.

The icon should disappear.  The *ugly* icon will reappear if there are any updates and hopefully frighten you into keeping your system fully updated ;-)